# I try to make a workers class but I got "pure virtual method called"

Tags: multithreading, c++11, abstract-class

I try to make an abstract class to parallelise some works. I would like to have something where I can put a lot of work and don't care about how it's done. But I have a strange bug, when I run it, I got a console output "pure virtual method called", but I don't have any problem when I compile it. C++ is intended to avoid that kind of call ? No ?

Here is my abstract class :

```
#ifndef LIBRARIES_PARALLELISABLEPROCESS_HPP
#define LIBRARIES_PARALLELISABLEPROCESS_HPP

/* C/C++ standard libraries */
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

/* Local inclusions */
namespace Libraries
{
    template< typename type_t >
    class ParallelisableProcess
    {
        public:

            void
            createTask (const type_t & data)
            {
                /* Adding works to the queue. */
                {
                    std::lock_guard< std::mutex > lock(m_pendingJobsAccess);

                    m_pendingJobs.emplace(data);
                }

                /* Try to start a worker if room there.
                 * Current worker ID to pass to process function. */
                auto workerID = 0;

                for ( auto & worker : m_workers )
                {
                    if ( worker.isActive )
                    {
                        workerID++;

                        continue;
                    }

                    /* Just making the process quit gently. */
                    if ( worker.process.joinable() )
                        worker.process.join();

                    std::cout << "Job given to worker #" << workerID << std::endl;

                    worker.isActive = true;
                    worker.process = std::thread(&ParallelisableProcess::process, this, workerID);

                    return;
                }

                std::cout << "All workers are busy ! " << m_pendingJobs.size() << " works pending." << std::endl;
            }

        protected:

            ParallelisableProcess (size_t workersCount)
                : m_workers(workersCount)
            {

            }

            virtual
            ~ParallelisableProcess (void)
            {
                for ( auto & worker : m_workers )
                {
                    if ( worker.process.joinable() )
                        worker.process.join();
                }
            }

            /** \brief This method takes care to pull out from the queue the next job. */
            bool
            getNextJob (type_t & data)
            {
                std::lock_guard< std::mutex > lock(m_pendingJobsAccess);

                if ( m_pendingJobs.size() > 0 )
                {
                    data = m_pendingJobs.top();

                    m_pendingJobs.pop();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            /** \brief Task keeper. */
            void
            process (int workerID)
            {
                type_t data;

                while ( this->getNextJob(data) )
                {
                    std::cout << "Launching a real task !" << std::endl;

                    this->task(data);
                }

                /* all jobs done, telling the process is inactive. */
                m_workers[workerID].isActive = false;
            }

            /** \brief The process to build in child class. */
            virtual void task (type_t & data) = 0;

        private:

            struct Worker
            {
                bool isActive = false;
                std::thread process;
            };

            std::vector< Worker > m_workers;
            std::mutex m_pendingJobsAccess;
            std::stack< type_t > m_pendingJobs;
    };
} /* End of namespace */

#endif /* LIBRARIES_PARALLELISABLEPROCESS_HPP */
```

And here is my simple test :

```
#include <ParallelisableProcess.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace Libraries;

class DumbassWorker final : public ParallelisableProcess< int >
{
    public:

        DumbassWorker (void)
            : ParallelisableProcess(4)
        {

        }

    private:

        virtual void
        task (int & data) override final
        {
            std::cout << "I'm working for " << data << " secondes.\n" << std::endl;

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s * data);

            std::cout << "My job is done sir !\n" << std::endl;
        }
};

int
main (int argc, const char * argv[], char * envp[])
{
    DumbassWorker worker;

    worker.createTask(5);
    worker.createTask(7);
    worker.createTask(9);
    worker.createTask(10);
    worker.createTask(15);
    worker.createTask(2);
    worker.createTask(4);
    worker.createTask(10);
    worker.createTask(5);
    worker.createTask(7);
    worker.createTask(9);
    worker.createTask(10);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why I got a call to a pure virtual method ? Maybe I'm blind, but I can't figure it out...

This is the output :

```
Job given to worker #0
Job given to worker #1
Job given to worker #2
Job given to worker #3
Launching a real task !
I'm working for 10 secondes.

Launching a real task !
I'm working for 9 secondes.

Launching a real task !
I'm working for 7 secondes.

All workers are busy ! 2 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 3 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 4 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 5 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 6 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 7 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 8 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 9 works pending.
Launching a real task !
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Le programme s'est terminé subitement. (***Come from french dev environement)
The process was ended forcefully.
```

Comment: My *guess* here is that the process ends before all threads have finished, which leads to the objects being destructed and weird things will happen as the objects are destructed while the threads are still running and perhaps calling `task` just before the exit. You need to wait until all jobs have finished before exiting the process (leaving `main`).

Comment: Yes, but, I ask to destructor (from Parallelisable object) to join all threads before being fully destroyed.

Comment: Do you think std::this_tread::sleep_for is not a good idea to fake work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you join threads in destructor of base class, at that point destructor of child was already called. Vptr changes to the class of the currently executed destructor.

Comment: Yes, it's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution... DumbassWorker destructor is called first which invalidate task() method from DumbassWorker class. So to get things waiting the end of all threads, I had to make a "wait" method in ParallelisableProcess that I called in the destructor of DumbassWorker to block execution, then the destructors are called in right order. It's not elegant, but it works...

Now the output is :

```
[ParallelisableProcess] Im built !
[DumbassWorker] Im built !
Job given to worker #0
Job given to worker #1
Job given to worker #2
Job given to worker #3
Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

All workers are busy ! 2 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 3 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 4 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 5 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 6 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 7 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 8 works pending.
All workers are busy ! 9 works pending.
[DumbassWorker] Im dying...
0 is waiting to die...
My job is done sir !.

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

My job is done sir !.

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

My job is done sir !.

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

My job is done sir !.

My job is done sir !.
My job is done sir !.

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !


Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

My job is done sir !.

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

My job is done sir !.

Launching a real task !
I'm starting a job !

My job is done sir !.

My job is done sir !.

Worker #My job is done sir !.
0 is killed !

1 is waiting to die...
My job is done sir !.

Worker #1 is killed !
2 is waiting to die...
Worker #2 is killed !
3 is waiting to die...
Worker #3 is killed !
I died
[ParallelisableProcess] Im dying...
```